Why is dropping a table from HBase a blocking operation?
After a lot of preparation work, today we were ready to drop our biggest HBase table (1 petabyte before replication) from the database. As needed, we started with disabling the table, this took 4 minutes.  After confirming nobody saw any issues, we proceeded to drop the table.
This process is now still running, 70 minutes into the task. It looks like all the region files are being deleted from HDFS before the HBase shell where the command to drop was given returns. This is affecting all other tables in the database, none of which are able to return answers. It appears to mostly be a problem with updates to the HBase:Meta table.
Why does HBase not return within a few seconds and let the region servers do their cleanup work as a background task?
